# Efficient way to analysis neighbours of subsets of nodes in large graph

Tags: r, igraph

I have a graph of 6 million of nodes such as

```
require(igraph)

# Graph of 1000 nodes
g <- ba.game(1000)
```

with the following four attributes defined for each node

```
# Attributes
V(g)$attribute1 <- V(g) %in% sample(V(g), 20)
V(g)$attribute2 <- V(g) %in% sample(V(g), 20)
V(g)$attribute3 <- V(g) %in% sample(V(g), 20)
V(g)$attribute4 <- V(g) %in% sample(V(g), 20)
```

Among the nodes I have a `subset` of 12,000 that are of particular interest:

```
# Subset of 100 nodes
V(g)$subset <- V(g) %in% sample(V(g), 100)
```

What I want to obtain is an analysis (count) of the neighbourhood of my `subset`. That is, I want to define

```
V(g)$neigh.attr1 <- rep(NA, vcount(g))
V(g)$neigh.attr2 <- rep(NA, vcount(g))
V(g)$neigh.attr3 <- rep(NA, vcount(g))
V(g)$neigh.attr4 <- rep(NA, vcount(g))
```

such that `NA` is replaced for every node in the `subset` with the corresponding count of neighbouring nodes with `V(g)$attribute{1..4}==TRUE`.

I can easily create a list of the neighbourhood of interest with

```
neighbours <- neighborhood(g, order = 1, V(g)[V(g)$subset==TRUE], mode = "out")
```

but I can't think of an efficient way to iterate over every `neighbours` and compute the statistics for each of the four attributes. Indeed the only way I've came up with is a loop which given the size of my original graph takes just too long:

```
subset_indices <- as.numeric(V(g)[V(g)$subset==TRUE])
for (i in 1:length(neighbours)) {
    V(g)$neigh.attr1[subset_indices[i]] <- sum(V(g)$attribute1[neighbours[[i]]])
    V(g)$neigh.attr2[subset_indices[i]] <- sum(V(g)$attribute2[neighbours[[i]]])
    V(g)$neigh.attr3[subset_indices[i]] <- sum(V(g)$attribute3[neighbours[[i]]])
    V(g)$neigh.attr4[subset_indices[i]] <- sum(V(g)$attribute4[neighbours[[i]]])
}
```

Comment: Do you simply want `degree()`?

Comment: @GaborCsardi No I want for each node in the `subset` the number of neighbours with `V(g)$attribute1==TRUE` , `V(g)$attribute2==TRUE` , `V(g)$attribute3==TRUE` and `V(g)$attribute4==TRUE` and store this information in `V(g)$neigh.attr{1...4}` of the node at the centre of the neighbourhood.

Comment: I see. If you want neighbors, then I guess you want `neighbors()`, or igraph's adjacency list notation: `G[[v]]`. If you do this for all vertices, then it is worth creating an adjacency list explicitly with `get.adjlist()`.